# Deploy a Workflow without changing the Content Type ID everytime

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio, content-type

I have a SharePoint 2010 State-Machine-Workflow with a custom Content Type. Everytime I want to deploy the Workflow to my test SharePoint Server I've to change the Content Type ID because it throws me an error that the current ID was found on the Server.
That's pretty annoying so I want to ask if there is a way to deploy the Workflow without changing the ID?

Edit:
When I want to build the project in VS2010 I got this error message until I change the Content Type ID (the message is translated by myself because my VS is in German, I hope it's ok :/)

`Error by "activate function": The Content Type with ID '0x010801...' that is defined in the feature '{...}' was already found in the current site collection.`

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please paste the full error..

Answer (score 0):

I set the deployment process of VS to "No Activation" now, so it needs a few more clicks to deploy the Workflow but that works fine.